# My "for loops" won't actually loop but it's not throwing any codes and I don't see a problem

Tags: java, loops

All of this is just for reference so you can see what's going on if you need to look. I'm creating a grid game with required fields and methods. Some of which I've added to the assignment for ease of use:

char[][] checkGameBoard

boxTop()

boxBottom()

printSubRows()

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class SweeperGame {
    private char[][] gameBoard;     // Represents the grid. [Rows][Columns]
                                    // For accessing, two nested for loops are needed that will sort, add, and track
    private char[][] checkGameBoard;

    private int treasureX;
    private int treasureY;
    private int totalMoves;
    private boolean found;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        // Driver File
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int height;
        int width;
        boolean done = false;
        int x;
        int y;

        do {
            System.out.println("Sweep the sand and find the treasure");
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of height and width"
                    + "\nof the game board");
            System.out.print("Height of board: ");
            height = s.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Width of board: ");
            width = s.nextInt();
            SweeperGame game = new SweeperGame(height, width);
            s.nextLine();
            do {
                do {
                    System.out.print("Enter treasure coordinates separated by a space: ");
                    x = s.nextInt();
                    y = s.nextInt();
                } while (!game.checkOutOfBounds(x, y) || game.beenSwept(x, y));
                done = game.digSand(x, y);
                System.out.println(game.toString());
                s.nextLine();
            } while (!done);
            System.out.println("You found the treasure in " + game.getTotalMoves() + " moves!");
            System.out.println("Out of " + game.getBoardHeight() * game.getBoardWidth() + " possible moves.");
            System.out.print("Would you like to find more treasure [Y/N]? ");
        } while (s.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    }

    public SweeperGame(int height, int width) {
        /*
        Receives two int parameters as the user's input for height and width of grid where treasure is buried
        instantiates the gameBoard array [x][y]
        Initialize gameBoard cells to contain a space ''. Done with single quotes only. (Why does the single quotes matter?)
        Set treasureX/treasureY randomly using the first/second parameter, respectively
        Set gameBoard[treasureX][treasureY] to 'T'
        Set total moves to 0
        Set found to false
         */

        totalMoves=0;
        found = false;

        // Build grid
        if (height == 0 && width == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        // Instantiates gameBoard
        gameBoard = new char[height][width];
        checkGameBoard = gameBoard;                 // Might have to move this to after set treasure. We'll see how it plays out

        // Initialize gameBoard's cells
        for (int i=0; i<height; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<width; j++){
                gameBoard[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        System.out.println("X is :" + gameBoard.length + ". Y is :" + gameBoard[1].length + ".");

        // Set treasureX
        Random randomX = new Random(width);
        treasureX = randomX.nextInt(width);

        // Set treasureY
        Random randomY = new Random(height);
        treasureY = randomY.nextInt(height);

        // Setting the treasure 'T' into the gameBoard
        gameBoard[treasureX][treasureY] = 'T';

    }

    public boolean beenSwept(int x, int y){         // Receives x & y and returns true if space has already been searched
        // Reversed because of dimensions
        if (checkGameBoard[x][y] == 'x'){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            checkGameBoard[y][x] = 'x';
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean treasureFound(int x, int y){     // Receives x & y and returns true if treasure is at given locations
        if (this.treasureX == x && this.treasureY == y){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean checkOutOfBounds(int x, int y){                      // Receives x & y and returns true if within array (gameBoard), false if not
        int h = gameBoard[1].length;    // X value of gameBoard
        int v = gameBoard.length;       // Y value of gameBoard
        if ((x > 0 && x <= h) && (y > 0 && y <= v)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int getBoardHeight(){                                        // Returns the height of the board
        return gameBoard.length;
    }
    public int getBoardWidth(){                                         // Returns the width of the board
        return gameBoard[1].length;
    }
    public int getTotalMoves(){                                         // Returns the total amount of moves taken
        return totalMoves;
    }

    public boolean digSand(int x, int y){           // Receives x & y and returns true if the treasure if found, false otherwise.
        if (x == treasureX && y == treasureY){      // Also displays "Manhattan distance" to treasure. Increment number of moves taken if the treasure isn't found and space hasn't been searched already
            found = true;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //if (beenSwept = true, add one to totalMoves)
            if (beenSwept(x,y)==true){
                totalMoves = totalMoves + 1;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the part that needs attention. My for-loops don't throw any codes but won't loop either. The output is just a singular line with some spaces which is just the part before "checkGameBoard[i][j]"
I'm trying to get the for-loop to cycle so that I can create the output that's commented out (at the very bottom)

```
    public String toString(){                       // Displays the current gameBoard array and it's contents except for the location of the treasure

        int rows = gameBoard.length;
        int columns = gameBoard[1].length;

        for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
            boxTop();
            printSubRows();                                 // Prints top and the sub-rows
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {                 // Columns of gameBoard
                return "|   " + checkGameBoard[i][j] + "   ";
            }
            printSubRows();
            return null;
        }
        boxBottom();
        return null;
        /*
        Prints the following:
        |       |       |       |       |
        |       |       |       |       |
        |       |       |       |       |
        |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |
        |       |       |       |       |
        |       |       |       |       |
        |       |       |       |       |
         */
    }

    public String boxTop(){
        return ("--------".repeat(gameBoard.length)+"\n");
    }
    public String boxBottom(){
        return "--------".repeat(gameBoard.length);
    }
    public String printSubRows(){
        String filler = ("|       ").repeat(gameBoard[1].length) + "\n";
        return (filler.repeat(3));    // 3 is the number of sub-rows before a character input is required for the grid.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rows = gameBoard.length;
int columns = gameBoard[1].length;
```

This looks suspicious.

**EDIT:** Use this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Spawner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Declaration/Construction/Initialization of listOfLists begins here. */
        List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(0);
        for(int rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++) {
            listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(0));
            for(int columns = 0; columns < 10; columns++) {
                listOfLists.get(rows).add(Integer.valueOf(rows * columns));
            }
        }
        /* Declaration/Construction/Initialization of listOfLists ends here. */
        
        
        /* What's the advantage of this construct? It is dynamic,
         * you are able to change its size while runtime. */        
        for(int rows = 0; rows < listOfLists.size(); rows++) {
            for(int columns = 0; columns < listOfLists.get(rows).size(); columns++) {
                System.out.print(listOfLists.get(rows).get(columns).intValue() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't have any way to get the length of each dimension since they're variable.

Comment: Arrays mustn't be dynamic, they need to be static, aka you need to know their dimensions.